# Get Wordpress Posts of Multiple Categories by Order and Descending Dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using get_posts to grap multiple posts from 4 different categories.

```
  $blog_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 12,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
          'taxonomy' => 'category',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => '',
      ), ),
  );

  $blogs = array();

  foreach ($cat_slugs as $slug)
  {
    $blogs_args['tax_query']['terms'] = $slug;
    $blogs[$slug] = get_posts($blogs_args);
  }
```

What I want is, I wanna get posts one from each category and date desc. Such as,

```
[Post1 From Cat1, Post1 from Cat2, Post1 from Cat3, Post1 from Cat4, Post2 from Cat1, Post2 from Cat2, Post2 from Cat3, Post2 from Cat4, ...]
```

Is there a query to get such data? The only way I could find is to get all posts from each category (4 different queries) and merge it one by one, which is a performance issue.

Thank you in advance,